# Navigating nodes/connections/objects in Facebook API + Python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I am connecting to Facebook fine with [pythonforfacebook](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook), I have an access token set up that grants me this information, but I don't know the correct syntax for getting a dictionary with my friends names and hometown. Can someone help me out as to how this should be corrected?

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI("access token")
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
print friends[hometown]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have `friends_hometown` permission also you need to explicitly request it as a field

```
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends", fields="hometown")
```

Then you cannot access hometowns like that you need to understand the data structure. `friends` holds `data` (which holds all your friends) and a `paging` parameter.

```
for fr in friends['data']:
    if 'hometown' in fr:
    print fr['id'] + ' ' + fr['hometown']['name']
```